# Usage of display property of flex box items

Tags: css, flexbox

Is there any benefit or reason to change display property of a flex box item?

Especially, I'm interested in using `display:block` and `display:inline-block`

Comment: please share code which you have tried so far

Comment: Benefit regarding what? Why do you want to use `flex` or `block` or `inline-block?`

Comment: We can't reply to this question, it depends on what you need to do...

Comment: So the question is essentially "does the `display` mode of flex items inside a `display: flex` container alter their behavior?"

Comment: @AlexanderNied Almost yes. My question is a bit wider, but you are right about this point

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the specifciation](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-items):

> The display value of a flex item is **blockified**: if the specified display of an in-flow child of an element generating a flex container is an **inline-level value**, it computes to its **block-level equivalent**. (See CSS2.1§9.7 [CSS21] and CSS Display [CSS3-DISPLAY] for details on this type of display value conversion.)

So basically, setting `inline-block` or `block` will do nothing as both will get computed to `block` but you can set `table` or `inline-table` and your flex item will behave as a table. Same thing if you set `inline-grid` or `grid`

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  margin:5px;
}

.box>div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

span {
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div>
    <span></span>

    <span></span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div style="display:inline-grid;">
    <span></span>

    <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

For the second case you can see it computes to `grid`

[image]

Comment: Does a regular `inline` get converted|treated as a block?

Comment: @tonitone120 yes inline will become block. Inline or inline-block both will behave as block