# Are flex items block level element?

Tags: css, flexbox

Flex items are element of flex level, but is that an element of the block level?

---

According to [Chapter 4 of CSS Flexible Box Layout Module Level 1](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-items), flex items are considered to be at the flex level and not at the block level.

> A flex item establishes an independent formatting context for its contents. **However, flex items themselves are flex-level
>   boxes, not block-level boxes**: they participate in their container’s flex formatting context, not in a block formatting context.

---

However, if you read chapter 4 later, it is written that the flex item's display value will be "blockified".

Does blockified indicate that the element is block level? If so, the "flex item is flex level" described above is a mistake.

> **The display value of a flex item is blockified**: if the specified display of an in-flow child of an element generating a flex container is an inline-level value, it computes to its block-level equivalent. (See CSS2.1§9.7 [CSS21] and CSS Display [CSS3-DISPLAY] for details on this type of display value conversion.)

---

What does "blockified" mean here? Also, are flex items at the flex level? Or is it a blockified block level?

If it interprets as a specification, it will be the contradictory conclusion that "flex item is flex level, not block level but it becomes block level by blockified".

Comment: _“What does "blockified" mean here?”_ - the word itself in that very place where you quoted this from, is already linked to the explanation …

Comment: I think that the explanation “flex items are at the flex level and not at the block level, but they become elements at the block level by being "blockified" is contradictory. Is not it contradictory that it is not the block level but it is the block level?

Comment: You’re kinda ignoring the word “become” here, no?

Answer (score 8):

Both specifications are, of course, correct, but you forget the keyword **display** in the second section. Each element has a display value and for flex items this value is `block` which means that if, for example, you specify `inline-block` it will get computed to `block`. If you specify `inline-grid`, it will get computed to `grid` and so on.

> if the specified display of an in-flow child of an element generating a flex container is an **inline-level value**, it computes to its **block-level equivalent**

So flex items are flex-level boxes with a `display: block;` value but they aren't block-level boxes.

Related: [Usage of display property of flex box items](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55380453/8620333)

---

To make it easier, imagine you have two worlds, the outside world and the inside world. If we look at a flex item from the outside world, it's a flex-level box participating in its container's flex formatting context. From the inside world, it's a block element which means that an element inside a flex item will see the flex item as a block element.

If you set `inline-[flex/table/grid/block]` to the flex item it will be seen as a `[flex/table/grid/block]` container from the inside. The `inline` is gone because it's **blockified**.