# CSS prevent div flex from stretching child

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The moment div has the `flex` display property it stretches the paragraph. I seem to be missing something but no property I can think to put on the flex div changes this. How can I prevent this behavior? (without the flex property I get the result on the right in the image)

[image]

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
}

p {
  background-color: green;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by _stretches_? You don't want  `p` element to take full width of the flex container?

Comment: Yes, edited the snippet to reflect that

Comment: You want your `p` to look like second image above ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping yes, without the flex property you get what's on the right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add another wrapper:

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align:center;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
}

p span{
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Related question to understand why your `inline` is ignored:

[Are flex items a block level element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55485802/8620333)

[Usage of display property of flex box items](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55380453/8620333)

Comment: But why? What exactly about flex causes this?

Comment: It's more important to understand that flex causes the bounding box around the element to change, so it would be a more practical solution to give the entire element a background, and work from that way.

Comment: @K41F4r because flex item are blockified

Comment: @K41F4r related question for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55496749/8620333

Answer (score 3):

```css
span { 
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
  -o-box-decoration-break: clone;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
  background-color: green;
}
div {
  text-align:center;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
  </span>
</div
```