# Why use display: block in a media query to override display: flex?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am looking at some HTML code, which looks like this (summarised):

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background: #1c1c1c;
}

header {
  background: #1c1c1c;
  display: flex;
}

.child {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
}

li {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:542px) {
  header div:nth-child(1) {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>

  <div class="child">
    <img src="logo.png" />
  </div>

  <ul class="child">
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Services</li>
    <li>Gallery</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
  </ul>


</header>
```

The `display:block` on the third line from bottom of the css has no effect and I find myself wondering what it is there for?

Comment: your code xample does nothing  `header div:nth-child(1) { display: block;}` is the default value of that element and never turns into a flex box . You probably missed something in your example.  Anyway, switching from flex to block can be useful *(ex:  `@media only screen and (max-width:542px) { header  { display: block;} }`  )* if you do not need the flex-column properties..

Comment: @G-Cyrillus , I defined header as a flex container further up in the .css?

Comment: Yes, but header div:nth-child(1) was not. It only is a flex child . If you did know about it yet : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ is handy. For the mediaquerie switching display: value is very comon too ;)

Comment: @G-Cyrillus, thanks.  I see.  Why does changing display from block to inline in the media query have no effect?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55380998/8620333 / https://stackoverflow.com/a/55496749/8620333

Answer (score 1):

It's not apparent in the code because there seem to be parts missing.

But here's the underlying logic:

- `display: flex` lines up child elements in a row
- `display: block` restores vertical stacking

So the override takes you out of flex layout and back to standard block layout (where flex properties have no effect).

This set-up can be handy for switching from a desktop to a mobile layout, among other use-case scenarios.

Here's a simplified version of the code for illustration purposes:

```css
.child {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

@media (max-width:542px) {
  .child {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="child">
  <li>About</li>
  <li>Services</li>
  <li>Gallery</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
```

[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8c41nswr/)