# HTML element position won't change

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a "easy" dashboard layout to get in touch with Css better. Now I have the problem my links are next to each othe instead of underneath.
`

```
<div class="column is-one-fourth menu">
                <a href="dashboard.html" class="fxlarge">Dashboard</a>
                <a href="dashboard.html" class="fxlarge">Account</a>
                <a href="dashboard.html" class="fxlarge">Help</a>
                <a href="dashboard.html" class="fxlarge fred">Logout</a>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.menu{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

I'm looking forward for your help,
thanks.

I treied to play around with justify-content and align items but nothing helped.

Comment: add: `flex-direction: column;` because by default is `row`

Comment: @PaulJ did `flex-direction: column` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just set the menu to be `flex-direction` to `column`, this will fix your issue.

```css
.menu{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;  
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: no need to make the link block

Comment: @TemaniAfif by default its `inline-block`, so settings it to `block` makes sense, as its being used as a block object within the `flex` container

Comment: by default it's inline (not inline-block) and it's not a block element when used inside flexbox container. It becomes a flex item (related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55485802/8620333) and the display value is blockified by default (https://stackoverflow.com/a/55380998/8620333) so it's useless to set display: block

Comment: @TemaniAfif well done.

Comment: @TemaniAfif https://stackoverflow.com/a/55496749/6651840