# Chrome does not respect display: inline on flexbox children

Tags: css, google-chrome, blink

How do I force Chrome to respect `display: inline !important;` in a flexbox parent when applied to it's child elements? Chrome *forces* elements to be displayed as `block` no matter what I set the `display` property to. ︎

**XML**

```
<fieldset>
<a></a>
<input />
</fieldset>
```

**CSS**

```
fieldset {align-items: center; display: flex;}
fieldset * {display: inline !important;}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28078681/ / https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55380453

Answer (score 1):

`display:inline` property doesn't work on children when the parent is using `display:flex` property. You have to use `flex-basis` and `flex-grow` properties to set children as requirements.

If still you want to force Chrome to treat children as `display: inline !important;` you can simply applied `justify-content: flex-start;` in the parent `div` something like this:

```
fieldset {
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: flex-start; /* or center */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can you please try:

```
inline-block
```

note: try inline-block instead of inline.

Comment: I tried that, Chrome refuses to use anything other than `block`.

Answer (score 0):

its a bug use other element instead of `fieldset` like div.
then you don't have to use display inline or display inline-block