# Element is not 100% width in div

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` with some elements. I want these elements to be `100%` width of the container `div`.

```css
.container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: scroll;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.inner {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  white-space: nowrap;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="inner">LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT</span>
  <span class="inner">XXX</span>
  <span class="inner">XXX</span>
</div>
```

As you can see if you horizontally scroll, the background is not `100%` complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the **flex** solution.

Replace `flex-direction: column` with `flex-flow: column wrap` in `.container`. And remove `width: 100%` from `.inner`.

And you get the desired result.

```css
.container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;
  /*flex-direction: column;*/
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  overflow: scroll;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.inner {
  /*width: 100%;*/
  background-color: gray;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="inner">LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT</span>
  <span class="inner">XXX</span>
  <span class="inner">XXX</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

update your code like below:

```css
.container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: scroll;
  border: 1px solid black;
  align-items:flex-start; /* disable the stretch alignment*/
}

.inner {
  min-width: 100%; /* min-width instead of width*/
  background-color: gray;
  white-space: nowrap;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="inner">LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT</span>
  <span class="inner">XXX</span>
  <span class="inner">XXX</span>
</div>
```

Or like below if you want all elements to get full coloration

```css
.container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  overflow: scroll;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.container>div {
  min-width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.inner {
  display:block;
  background-color: gray;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <span class="inner">LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT</span>
    <span class="inner">XXX</span>
    <span class="inner">XXX</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want **all** element inside to be of complete 100% width

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE: I have came up with this non-flexbox solution (A curiosity driven actioin)** `Initially I misunderstood the question`.

**SOLUTION 1:** Adding a `wrapper` div around your `spans`.

```css
.container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow-x:scroll;
}

.wrapper{
  background:orange;
  height:auto;
  width:max-content;
}
.inner{
  display:block;
  min-width:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <span class="inner">LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT</span>
    <span class="inner">XXX</span>
    <span class="inner">XXX</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not what I am looking for as solution. I want the text to be only in 1 line.

Comment: we don't need to add display:block because flex item are blockified by default: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55380998/8620333

Comment: @Temani: I agree, I didn't checked the container flex property

Comment: @TalRofe : Yup, I didn't understood it fully :) Temani Afif has it right

Comment: @TemaniAfif : Hi Mate ! Have updated my answer now ;) A came up with a non flexbox solution. Since 2 answers are already using flexbox :) Please have a look :)

Comment: this not what the OP want, each block need to take its own line and have full coloration

Comment: Ya I realized this and have just updated again... I can also make smal changes in the previous example :) Please have a look now :)

Comment: won't work if the content is short: https://jsfiddle.net/e1384xtc/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227185/discussion-between-imran-rafiq-rather-and-temani-afif).

Comment: @TemaniAfif Dear Friend :)  hope this answer would also be helpful in future :) Leaving the room, since you didn't replied there :)

Answer (score -1):

Just put a display: block in the span elements because their default display is inline, and that's why they behave the way they are behaving,

Comment: we don't need to add display:block because flex item are blockified by default: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55380998/8620333